# Finding duplicate in sql with two columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have records in SQL server as

```
c_num   c_date      invoice
---------------------------
 11213  2015-07-21   96914
 11213  2015-07-21   96915
133412  2015-09-30  137389
133412  2015-09-30  137450
202793  2016-12-28  390045
202793  2016-12-28  390047
   379  2016-12-15  393380
   379  2017-06-29  510412
```

I need to find `c_num` having multiple `c_date` .

I tried below SQL, but it does not help as this table can have multiple `c_num` but every `c_num` should ideally have one `c_date`. I am trying to find c_num having multiple c_date which in this example is 379 . Expected result is 379.

```
select 
    c_num, c_date, count(*)  
from 
    table_a 
group by 
    c_num, c_date 
having 
    count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Can you `Count(c_date)` and `Group By c_num`?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to include an expected output for the sample data given

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query    (not tested)

```
select 
c_num, count(DISTINCT c_date)  
from table_a 
group by   c_num
having  count(DISTINCT  c_date) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - 
using a common table expression is not necessary, but helps clean up.

`with cte as 
         ( select distinct c_num, c_date from table_a  ) 
  select distinct c_num, 
         count(*) 
  from cte 
  group by c_num 
  having count(*) > 1`

Comment: Your answer don't consider distinct values, returning more results than should.

Comment: you can add distinct after select where needed.

Comment: of course you can, but since the question ask this and your answer don't cover this case, your answer is "wrong". I commented to let you know, so you can adjust your answer and add the needed `DISTINCT`.